# Oracle SQL - Referencing another column within a wildcard statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select, match, wildcard

[I am trying to select only the rows the DIAGCODE column and PRESUMPTIVE column are similar. That is the first three characters of both the columns match each other. How do I self reference a cell within a like statement?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWotZ.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour], read [ask], and post a [mcve] .   You will get a better response that way. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Assuming the two columns contain `VARCHAR2` data or similar, it should be as easy as `where substr(diagcode, 3) = substr(presumptive, 3)`.

Comment: mathguy is right. If you insist on it being a like then `diagcode like substr(presumptive, 3) || '%'` should work as well. Be careful where the strings are shorter than 3 characters. And in the future you'll be expected to write better questions.

Comment: Thank you all. I completely forgot about the substr functio.